# Algorithm for MinMax of a function doesn't work as intended

Tags: python, algorithm, integer

i'm just starting coding to help my son, and I drafted a few lines to get the Min Max of a function over a definite interval.
However, the Min value displayed is not an integer, and I can't figure out why...
Here is the code :

```
a=float(input("Valeur de a ?"))
b=float(input("Valeur de b ?"))
pas=float(input("Valeur du pas ?"))
val_max=a**2
val_min=a**2
while a<b+pas:
    if a**2>val_max:
        val_max=a**2
    if a*2<val_min:
        val_min=a**2
    a=a+pas
print("Maximum :",val_max)
print("Minimum :",val_min)
```

And here is the output :

Valeur de a ?-4

Valeur de b ?3

Valeur du pas ?0.1
Maximum : 16.0
Minimum : 5.830945499626795e-30

Why isn't the minvalue 0 instead of this 5.8^-30 thingy?

Comment: You are missing a `*` here: `if a*2<val_min`.

Comment: Which language is this? Python?

Comment: You declare a and b as float, and expect the result to be int?

Comment: `a=float(input("Valeur de a ?"))` => `a=int(input("Valeur de a ?"))`

Comment: Raising a float less than 1 to the power of two will approach zero but never become zero.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the value a=0 which would give min = 0 is never tested.
When you enter 0.1 as value for pas, it is converted to a binary representation, but 1/10 is equal to 0.000110011001100110011001100110011... in binary. The program rounds it to something like 0.000110011001100110011 which is .099999904632568359375. This way you never fall exactly on zero and you don't get the expected value for min.

Comment: I updated the code with jingx correction, and still get this "almost 0" result. So I guess @Mitchel0022 explanation is the right one, along with the more detailed one you posted. Thank to all of you !